# How to add all screen compatible images that aren't square?

Tags: android-studio

I want to add images to my app on Android Studio, and account for the different screen compatibilities by adding the hdpi, xhdpi, etc of the images, but one of them is 512x133 and I'm not sure how to adjust the resolution for this one.

It will be used for an Image Button as well..

Thanks!